# Inductive type constructed by a list of that type in Lean

Tags: type-theory, lean

I would like to define an inductive type that can be constructed from a list of itself in lean.  However

```
inductive a : Type :=
| aFromAs : list a → a
```

gives the error:

```
failed to infer inductive datatype resultant universe, provide the universe levels explicitly
```

Fine, so I `set_option pp.universes true` and `list` belongs to the type universe of its parameter (unless the parameter is Prop).  So if `a` is `Type₁` everything should be fine.  But

```
inductive a : Type₁ :=
| aFromAs : list a → a
```

gives the error

```
arg #1 of aFromAs contains an non valid occurrence of the datatype being declared
```

It looks valid to me. This seams like it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lean 3 now supports nested inductive declarations:

```
inductive a : Type
| aFromAs : list a → a
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Lean doesn't have support for nested datatypes](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/wiki/Inductive-datatypes#encoding-datatypes-that-contain-recursive-occurrences-nested-in-existing-datatypes) so your best bet to encode them as mutually recursive definitions:

```
inductive a := node : as -> a
with as :=
   | nil  : as
   | cons : a -> as -> as
```